# Thread Communication when Debug mode and Release Mode

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, release

Threads does not communicate each other while release mode but they do communicate while debug mode. Also Threads do communicate if i make thread sleep for 0.1 second while release mode. Why it is happening ? There are example for you.

main.cpp

```
int main(){
bool foo=false;


thread tk(control,ref(foo));
tk.detach();
this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
foo=true;
while(true){
//it is for program is not finished

}
}
```

foo.cpp

```
void control(bool &x){
while(x==false){
   //When release mode, program cannot go out from this.
}

}
```

And There are working example for you

main.cpp

```
int main(){
bool foo=false;


thread tk(control,ref(foo));
tk.detach();
this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
foo=true;
while(true){
//it is for program is not finished

}
}
```

foo.cpp

```
void control(bool &x){
while(x==false){
  this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
//it can go out.
}

}
```

Comment: You have a _data race_ in your code. Make `foo` a variable of `std::atomic<bool>` type. Also, `control` needs to pass its argument _by reference_, not _by value_.

Comment: it solved my question @DanielLangr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They gave you the correct answer in the comments.

Using a plain `bool` to communicate between threads creates a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model):

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless
>
> - both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal handler, or
> - both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see `std::atomic`), or
> - one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see `std::memory_order`)
>
> If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined.

The fix is to use `std::atomic<bool>` instead of `bool`.